# Ionic V3 | ngFor no imprime los childs Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic, lista

Tengo un provider (se llama auth.ts) que busca un nodo en Firebase:

```
datosUsuarioActual(){
var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
let uid = user.uid; 
return this.afDB.list('Usuarios/' + uid).valueChanges();
```

}

Y en el controlador, capturo el resultado:

```
user:Observable<any[]>;

  constructor(...) {
   this.user = this.auth.datosUsuarioActual();
  }
```

Y en la vista lo imprimo de la siguiente forma:

```
<div *ngFor='let u of user | async'>
  {{u}}
</div>
```

Hasta aqui ningun problema.
La vista imprime todos los datos guardados en el nodo, pero al querer acceder a un atributo en espesifico, no imprime nada. 
Ejemplo, si coloco:

```
<div *ngFor='let u of user | async'>
  {{u.nombre}} <br>
  {{u.email}}
</div>
```

El resultado no sera ninguno.
Alguna idea?
Gracias de antemano. Slds

Comment: Solucionado: Asigne el json a un arreglo, para de esa manera imprimir el indice que quiera y no todos lo datos.  this.auth.datosUsuarioActual().subscribe(valores => this.datosUsuario = valores);